# Is there any way to start your computer at a certain time with a python script?

Tags: python

Is any way to use a python script to start my computer every day at a certain time? I would like to have it start my computer every day at a time at which I usually wake up.

Comment: How do you expect a computer that is not on to start itself up?

Comment: You should google around for info on wake on lan.

Comment: if you use a server class box which has BMC(baseboard management controller), you can use ipmitool to initiate power operations remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to a remote computer you could always try to check your BIOS for something in the likes of `"Power ON by Alarm"`

[This](http://askville.amazon.com/set-computer-boot-up-automatically/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=4933774) answers most of what you may ask. You should check your BIOS for this option. If it has, perfect, if it hasn't, resort to the previous answer. If neither, well... it's pretty much impossible.

To access a BIOS, you usually press F2 or F8 at computer (not system) startup. However, things can differ a lot from PC to PC including laptops.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot run a python script on a computer that is Switched off. 
You could however run a python script on a different computer which remotely boots up the target machine if the machine you want to start supports remote wake. 
Check this link out http://www.instructables.com/id/Starting-your-linux-box-remotely/ for more  details.